# how do I determine subsite template

Tags: site-template, sub-site

how do i find out what template was used to create a sub-site in SharePoint? I want to know what template was used when creating one of the sub-sites in my SharePoint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to do this in chrome: go to the home page (or any page really) of the sub site you want to check. open the Chrome menu and select More Tools > Developer Tools. View the page source and do a ctrl+f and search for "var g_wsaSiteTemplateId". This will give you a value like = STS#0 or something like that. That value tells you what the site template was.

Reference https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html to see what the values mean